# Go html/template & escaping

Tags: html, go, templates, escaping, auto

Based on the example in the `html/template` documentation I can't say I fully understand why it appears that less and greater than are inconsistently escaped in my experiment:
https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#hdr-Introduction

Does this warrant a bug report? I am holding off since I am relatively new to Go.

```
$ go version
go version go1.16 linux/amd64
```

I saw similar behavior with `go1.15.8`.

```
package main

import (
        htmltemplate "html/template"
        "os"
        texttemplate "text/template"
)

type MyVars struct {
        Flavor string
}

func main() {
        Vars := MyVars{
                Flavor: "#####   html   #####",
        }

        htmlTmpl, _ := htmltemplate.ParseFiles("index.html")
        htmlTmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, Vars)

        Vars = MyVars{
                Flavor: "#####   text   #####",
        }

        textTmpl, _ := texttemplate.ParseFiles("index.html")
        textTmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, Vars)
}
```

```
$ cat index.html
{{ .Flavor }}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
< span >Hello< /span >
<span>Hello</span>
{{ "<" }}span{{ ">" }}Hello{{ "<" }}/span{{ ">" }}
```

```
$ ./experiment                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#####   html   #####
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> # Why is only < escaped?
&lt; span >Hello&lt; /span >                              # Why is only < escaped?
<span>Hello</span>                                        # Why is neither < nor > escaped?
&lt;span&gt;Hello&lt;/span&gt;
#####   text   #####
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
< span >Hello< /span >
<span>Hello</span>
<span>Hello</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
1: {{ .Flavor }}
2: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
3: < span >Hello< /span >
4: <span>Hello</span>
5: {{ "<" }}span{{ ">" }}Hello{{ "<" }}/span{{ ">" }}
```

The `<` on lines 2 and 3 are text. The HTML template package escapes `<` in text to prevent a document reader from misinterpreting the `<` as the start of a tag.

The `>` on lines 2 and 3 is written as is to the output. There is no security benefit to escaping the `>`.

The `<` and `>` on line 4 are part of a tag.  Tags are not escaped.

The `<` and `>` on line 5 are the value of an expression.  The HTML template package fully escapes expression results.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I suspected it may be something along those lines. If nothing else it may be beneficial to have the documentation updated to illustrated the difference in behavior for the calls I used versus their existing example.

Comment: The documentation omits one detail:  The text literal `<` is escaped to `&lt;`.  Everything else is documented or shown in an example.